# Java applet error

Tags: java, netbeans, applet

I am doing a project on applets. I designed the applet using netbeans. After building the project in netbeans, I took the directory "classes" and a .html file from the "build" directory and moved it to another new directory. This .html file includes the applet. The .html file displays the applet correctly, when it is viewed from my desktop.

I uploaded the "classes" folder and the .html file to my free server (host4ufree.com) using FileZilla. If I try to view the webpage online, I get the following error instead of the applet getting displayed:

java.lang.ClassFormatError: Extra bytes at the end of class file

I am using JDk 1.6.0 update 18, and uploaded the file using FileZilla both ASCII and binary format manner. Yet, I am not able to solve the error problem. Does anybody know the solution to this? Is there something wrong in the manner in which I'm trying to add the applet to my webpage?

Comment: I know you said you already tried it, but triple check that you uploaded the class files in binary mode.

Comment: Try downloading the files using a web browser (or wget) and check to see they are the same (same length, for instance).

Comment: Take a look at this also http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/deployment/deployment-guide/upgrade-guide/article-01.html

Comment: Take a look of [this answer][1]. Maybe you are using some kind of bad file names.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045422/java-lang-classformaterror-extra-bytes-at-end-of-class-file

Answer (score 0):

The question is quite unclear :S Anyway...

> I uploaded the "classes" folder and the .html file to my free server
>   (host4ufree.com) using FileZilla.

If your applet contains more that one class I do not recommend upload the project classes folder itself but wrap your applet classes to jar file before [delpoying](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/deployingApplet.html) it.

---

Report if that helped