# java.lang.ClassFormatError: Extra bytes at the end of class file

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

I generated a `jar` using `sbt assembly` but when I am trying to run the `jar` I am getting the below error. I am using `scala 2.12.0`, `sbt 0.13.8` and `assembly 0.14.2`. Can anyone help me out what this error means and the resolution?

```
Error: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Extra bytes at the end of class file
```

Comment: Maybe related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045422/java-lang-classformaterror-extra-bytes-at-end-of-class-file

Comment: solved using below lines in build.sbt
  `assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
   case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
   case "reference.conf" => MergeStrategy.concat
   case x => MergeStrategy.first
  }`

Comment: Can you answer you post yourself and accept the answer so that others can benefit from it too

Comment: How would I answer my question? I cannot find any option to post ans

Comment: @ArunavaS, there is a big text area with title "**Your Answer**" in the bottom of the page and a blue "**Post Your Answer**" button just under it. Your reputation should be enough to post an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 1):

The OP posted a viable solution in the comments, but never made it into an actual answer. Since I encountered the same problem today and his comment solved it, I'll post this solution as an answer below.

-- *answer from the OP, originally posted in the comments* --

Solved using below lines in build.sbt

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case "reference.conf" => MergeStrategy.concat
  case x => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

I'll just add that in my case, the critical addition was the middle `case "reference.conf"` which must trigger a `concat` merge strategy.